# Question about convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

$\textbf{Statement:}$  Let $\Phi:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.Then $\Phi$ is convex if and only if for each closed subinterval $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$ we have,
\begin{equation}
    \Phi(x)=\Phi(c)+\int_{c}^{x}\phi(t)dt : c\leq x\leq d......(1),
\end{equation}
where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotone non-decreasing and left continuous function. Also, $\Phi$ has left and right derivatives at each point of $(a,b)$ and they are equal except perhaps for at most a countable number of points.

can someone explain what does left continuity of $\phi$ means and how to prove it?I am finding it difficult to visualize it geometrically.

Comment: A convex function defined on an open set is locally Lipschitz and hence absolutely continuous,

Comment: You first get a monotone function $\phi $satisfying (1) and then replace it by $\phi (t-)$ to get a left continuous function.

Comment: what if I replace that by $\phi(t+)$?

Answer (score 0):

Left continuity means

$$\lim_{x \to c^-}f(x) = f(c)$$

Or that we approach it from below. For example, $1_{>0}(x)$ is left continuous, but not right continuous at $x=0$